# Can a player place boats while inside the spawn protection radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Can a survival mode player place their boat item while in a spawn protected area? Talking about the spawn protection setting in server.properties which allows server owners to define the radius of how much area around spawn should be protected from grief.

This [Minecraft Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_protection) did mention there are some indirect ways to bypass it, but it doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: Might test it later, but if it does work and you don't want players putting boats everywhere at spawn you can setup a command block to /kill all the boats with dx dy and dz arguments to decide the area where to get rid of boats